# Backbone & Laravel - Errors

Tags: backbone.js, laravel, error-handling, frontend, backend

I have been struggling with errors between backbone and laravel as of late. Not as to how to ensure that they are sent and received but rather what is considered best practice in sending and receiving errors. Heres a basic example of one way I have been implementing..

Laravel:

```
if(!$user->count()){
   $response = "No records were found matching your request";
   App::abort(401, $response);
} else{
   $response['reponse'] = "User updated!";
   return Response::json($response);
}
```

Backbone:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/test",
    type: "PUT",
    data: sendInfo,
    success: function(resp) {
      alert(resp);
    },
    error: function(err){
      alert(err.error);
    }
 });
```

The error in the bb example isn't correct, but generally speaking I'm just trying to find out what the best appropriate way of dealing w. backend -> frontend errors.

Thanks

Comment: Your question seems to be pretty broad and at least partially opinion based. The only "bad" thing I spotted in your code is that you're using the 401 HTTP Error Code which means "Unauthorized" [more information on HTTP Status Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) More fitting would be 404 "Not found"
If you want more detailed advice, maybe tell us more about the requirements of your application.

Comment: thanks, I have been using the appropriate error tags, wrote this simply as an example and wasn't thinking. Should be a 404. I'm using something like this for a password reset or a validation error. I know this is very broad, I just was unsure since no matter what I see the errors come through in the console and was curious if this was appropriate or if I should be doing anything different.

Comment: Alright ;) Yes (in my opinion) there's no problem with errors showing up in the console. The normal user won't open the console. Hell they don't even know it's there...
HTTP Error codes are there for a reason, use them.